# Necessito de "pontos" ou "votos" para ganhar medalha de bronze, prata e ouro por tag?

Tags: suporte, tags

Ontem tirei esta print:

[image: ontem]

- Tag [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) 942 pontos
- Tag [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) 511 pontos

Hoje eu ganhei +10 de um upvote:

[image: hoje]

- Tag [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) 944 pontos
- Tag [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) 514 pontos

Se entendi então não são os pontos que contam, mas sim a quantidade de *upvotes vs downvotes*, ou seja o total de upvotes subtraindo o total de downvotes. Talvez seja um erro de tradução.

Comment: Exatamente isso, já relatado em: [Palavra “pontos” deveria ser “votos” em se tratando de medalhas de tag](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4637/91)

Comment: Obrigado @rray é isso mesmo